# $M > 0$ such that for any partition $\{x_0, ... , x_n \}$ of $[a, b]$, $ \sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{|F(x_k)-F(x_{k-1}|^p}{|x_k-x_{k-1}|^{p-1}}\le M.$

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

For $1 < p < \infty$, show that if the absolutely continuous function $F$ on $[a, b]$ is the indefinite integral of an $L^P[a, b]$ function, then there is a constant $M > 0$ such that for any partition $\{x_0, ... , x_n \}$ of $[a, b]$,

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{|F(x_k)-F(x_{k-1})|^p}{|x_k-x_{k-1}|^{p-1}}\le M.$$

I am not getting clue to do the problem. Help Needed.

Comment: You could start by applying the fundamental theorem of calculus. What is $F(x_k) - F(x_{k-1})$?

Comment: since $F$ is a indefinite integral of an $L^P[a,b]$ function then $F(x)-F(a)=\int_a^xf(s)ds$ for some $f \in L^P[a,b]$

Comment: You'll ultimately want to apply H$\ddot{\text{o}}$lder's inequality, with the second function the indicator of the interval $[x_{k-1},x_{k}]$.

Comment: And specifically, $f = F'$ with $F' \in L^p$. Now follow @RideTheWavelet 's suggestion and apply Holder to the integral.

Comment: simplifying we can get $\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{|F(x_k)-F(x_{k-1})|^p}{(x_k-x_{k-1})^{{p-1}}} \le \sum_{k=1}^n \int_{x_{k-1}}^{x_k} |f|^p.$

Comment: but how to show it is less than some M

Comment: You are within $\epsilon$ of the answer. What is the last sum equal to?